# jQuery if only 1 item inArray

Tags: jquery, arrays

Ok, so I have this jquery function to that grabs the checkbox's value and uses as identifier to show or hide an ul

The problem is that I couldn't manage to add an if only 1 choice in checkbox add X.

Here is the code and what I have tried

```
$('#filter li input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        var show = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
           return $(this).val();
        });
        if (show.length > 0)
        {
                $('#list li').each(
                function(){
                    /*if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) <= 1)
                    {
                        console.log($(this));
                    }
                    else */if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) > -1)
                    {                        
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });
        }
        else {
            $('#list li').show();
        }
    });
```

I don't really understand how this works: `if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) > -1)` because I have tried `if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) = 1)` and nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning a value in the `if` clause:

```
if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) = 1)
```

To break it down, what this is actually saying is equivalent to

```
$.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) = 1;
if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show))
{
    ...
```

You should use the `==` comparison operator

```
if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) == 1)
```

Or, more correctly avoiding type coersion, use `===`

```
if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) === 1)
```

This will avoid comparison between `1` and `"1"` returning true

Comment: sorry, I should've removed that before posting... it is not the case... I need to fix the `if` inside `$('#list li').each(...`

Comment: Errrr, well, same applies. Use the `===` instead. `if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) === 1)`

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work. I have tried `if ($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) == 1)` and also `=== 1` and the alert that I added doesn't popup

Comment: Well, what is the value of the thing you are checking. I.e. do `alert($.inArray($(this).attr('class'),show) )` and see what you get. If it is equal to 0,2,3,4, etc then the condition will not be met.